# MVC - Download .Zip, and refresh page

Tags: file, model-view-controller, redirect, refresh

So I did ask this question already, but I didn't get a suitable answer. So I will try again.

I have a method that is called when I click a button.
The button currently returns a .Zip file

```
return File(directory + @"\Issues.zip", "appicaltion/zip", "IssueReports.zip");
```

That's great at all, but I would like to refresh the page too. I've been looking all over and I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. I don't know how something like this could be so difficult to answer.

But I will here, waiting patiently for an answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could call the action with ajax and when success use JS to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, I just wanted the page to refresh a few seconds after the download button was selected. I primarily wanted the view to show an updated download count to and date.

After trying several okay options, I settled on the following simple solution:

In the View I added an onclick event to the download button that called the following script. Everything else stayed the same:

```
function ReloadAfterDelay()
{
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.reload(1);
    }, 5000);
}
```